# how to resign .i.e remove the badge value from the tabba from other tab bar

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

Can any one help me in this:

I have three tabs, the first is message tab, the last is home tab.
If i tap button in home view, it should take me to 'message' tab. This is working fine.

But when i have a badge value in 'message' tab , badge value is not removed when the tab is shifted to 'messages'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

When you set the value on a UITabBarItem like this;

```
[tabBarItem setBadgeValue:@"2"];
```

You can remove it like this;

```
[tabBarItem setBadgeValue:nil];
```

P.S: Please consider adding more tags (such as ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, etc) to your future posts.

Comment: I used the same , its not working. If I tapped on the tab(containing badge value) its reseting . When came to the same tab using [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; its not resetting the badge value.